# Sound issues with HP Pavilion 15-cs1056

Tags: sound

First time Elementary OS user here.

I'm having an issue with my HP Pavilion 15-cs1056. The problem is the audio poor quality, low volume and no bass. Everything works, but the sound is very flat, low and no bass.

Here my soundcard info http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=d047f887d16337df939323230f29a11be3e61cc9

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to update to the latest kernel 5.5.13